# How to convert command prompt command into .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a one command to invoke some application from the command promt, once the command is fired the application starts.

I want to convert this command into the .bat file, so that on clicking .bat file, my application should invoke.

Also in similar way I want to convert my java  class to convert into batch file?

Comment: please refer the below link to create batch file using some command and run that file from command line.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your command in a text file (`file.txt`) and save it as  a `.bat` file, `file.bat`

So a sample file would look like this:

```
@echo off
echo hello this is my file, running my application
myapplication.exe
echo the file has been executed...
pause
```

**EDIT**

As for the `java` question, I did not answer initially because I don't understand what you are asking as it is quite vague. But if I am guessing correctly, I assume that you want to write batch files with a java program, in that case, just build up a string with your commands and write it to file with a `FileWriter`

Comment: yeah frnd..its working..thx..but wht abt java class to batch file..??

Comment: Yes, what about the Java classes? You answered only incomplete!

Comment: Sorry, but there are cases where this will result in an invalid bat file. For example, if you use a command on the prompt `for /l %x in (1, 1, 100) do ( echo %x )` which works, versus in a bat file which requires the `%` to be escaped `for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do ( echo %%x )`. Some type of explicit conversion is actually needed in some cases. In _most_ cases it will work, but some rare cases might fail. In either case, the OP's intentions will be satisfied by doing it verbatim. (I came from Google searching for this answer and didn't get an answer I needed, "use it as is" won't work for me)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

1. Open notepad
2. Write a single like containing *`"C:\YourFilePath\yourExeFileName.exe`*"
3. Click File -> Save As...
4. Change the "Text Documents" drop down box to say "All Files"
5. type *`newFileName.bat`* in the name field
6. Save it where you want it
7. Run it